# Number of lines in a tic tac toe of width $w$ and dimension $d$

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, tic-tac-toe

I was watching a video by pbs infinite series on tic-tac-toe(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FwJZa-helig). Here, they discuss if there is a winning strategy for the starting player in tic-tac-toe of dimension $d$ and width $w$ . I was trying to calculate the number of lines that are possible in a board, i.e, no. of lines that can result in a win for a board of arbitrary dimension and width. I want a formula which gives No. of lines $= f(d,w)$ . For example, a $3*3$ tic tac toe has $8$ winning lines. For $2$ dimension, it is easy to see that this number is $2*(w+1) , w$ horizontal, $w$ vertical and $2$ diagonal. But I couldn't generalize this to arbitrary dimensions.

Comment: For each dimension, you either want to have it be fixed, vary from "left to right", or vary from "right to left".  How many total types of winning lines are there (given that my method is overcounting) and how many of each are there?

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking in similar terms. But you need to have at least 1 dimension that is increasing or decreasing. Also, 1 dimension increasing and other decreasing is different from both increasing.

Comment: right, and reversing all of the directions gives you the same line, and the number of lines of each type is $w$ to the power of the number of fixed dimensions.  Beyond that, it's just a gross summation.

Comment: @MatthewDaly I think I have figured out the answer. Do check for any mistake

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I have solved this question. After some thinking, you can find that the formula is $\frac{(w+2)^d-(w)^d}{2}$. This comes if you index the tic tac toe board. Now, the valid lines are ones in which 1 or more indexes are changing. The total ways in which indexes can increase or decrease or remain the same is $(w+2)^d$. You also have to subtract the cases in which all the indexes remain the same, which are $w^d$. Also, the cases in which the indexes follow the reverse order are the same, i.e, one index increasing and the other decreasing is the same as one decreasing and other increasing. Hence, a factor of 2 has to be divided.